# Openlayer 3 rectangular selection

Tags: overlay, openlayers-3, drawrectangle, ol3-google-maps

I have added some overlays in openlayer 3.Is it possible that if i click on ctrl+mouse left click and drag mouse to select a rectangular area  on map  and i need to get the overlays listed in that particular area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with the DragBox element.

This way you declare the element:

```
var dragBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox({
    condition: ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly
});
```

And you can add it as interaction to your already existing map:

```
map.addInteraction(dragBox);
```

If you want to add some behavior, it is possible to call the events boxstart and boxend:

```
dragBox.on('boxstart', function() {
    // Your stuff when the box starts being drawn
});
dragBox.on('boxend', function() {
    // Your stuff when the box is already drawn
});
```

You will find more information in the OpenLayers 3 API: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.interaction.DragBox.html

You can also take a look at the Box Selection example here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/box-selection.html

Comment: This was helpfull